# Sphinx -python3 -m http.server - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python-sphinx

**My Question** - How to find out which file / directory is being missed ?

The Python3 http server was serving the Sphinx html files locally , but then suddenly it stopped serving them - i get this error in the terminal - am not sure which file / directory is missing ?

```
/pycon-sphinx-tutorial/crawler/docs/_build/html$ python3 -m http.server 8989
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8989 ...
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 60996)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 313, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 341, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 354, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 681, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 422, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 410, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 645, in do_GET
    f = self.send_head()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 669, in send_head
    path = self.translate_path(self.path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 785, in translate_path
    path = os.getcwd()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
----------------------------------------
^C
Keyboard interrupt received, exiting.
dhankar@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:/media/dhankar/Dhankar_1/a5_test_sphinx/pycon-sphinx-tutorial/crawler/docs/_build/html$ cd ..
dhankar@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:/media/dhankar/Dhankar_1/a5_test_sphinx/pycon-sphinx-tutorial/crawler/docs/_build$ ls -ltr
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 dhankar dhankar 4096 Oct 30 00:19 doctrees
drwxrwxr-x 4 dhankar dhankar 4096 Oct 30 00:19 html
dhankar@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:/media/dhankar/Dhankar_1/a5_test_sphinx/pycon-sphinx-tutorial/crawler/docs/_build$ cd html
dhankar@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:/media/dhankar/Dhankar_1/a5_test_sphinx/pycon-sphinx-tutorial/crawler/docs/_build/html$ ls -ltr
total 36
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dhankar dhankar 3849 Oct 30 00:19 index.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dhankar dhankar 3346 Oct 30 00:19 install.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dhankar dhankar 3694 Oct 30 00:19 support.html
drwxrwxr-x 2 dhankar dhankar 4096 Oct 30 00:19 _sources
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dhankar dhankar 2629 Oct 30 00:19 genindex.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dhankar dhankar 3120 Oct 30 00:19 search.html
drwxrwxr-x 2 dhankar dhankar 4096 Oct 30 00:19 _static
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dhankar dhankar  979 Oct 30 00:19 searchindex.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dhankar dhankar  295 Oct 30 00:19 objects.inv
dhankar@dhankar-VPCEB44EN:/media/dhankar/Dhankar_1/a5_test_sphinx/pycon-sphinx-tutorial/crawler/docs/_build/html$
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception is being raised, as you can see, from `os.getcwd()`.  This would suggest that you, or some other process, deleted the directory you were serving files from while the server was running.  If your current working directory is removed, then subsequent calls to `os.getcwd()` will raise `FileNotFound`.  For example:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.mkdir('a')
>>> os.chdir('a')
>>> os.getcwd()
'/blah/blah/blah/a'
>>> os.rmdir(os.getcwd())
>>> os.getcwd()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

So I guess, don't do that.

Comment: Thanks i upvoted ur answer . I have been following along the tutorial here - it clearly states that i make the HTML build using the code snippet  "make clean html" . Quote from the Tutorial -- "Fix this by running a make clean html, which will force a full rebuild." Tutorial URL = https://sphinx-tutorial.readthedocs.io/start/ . Am thus presuming that the ```make clean html``` recreates my directory and the ```os.getcwd()``` will not have the same structure of sub directories within the Current Working Directory - but then no one else on the internet seems to be having this issue , thanks.

Comment: The basic `http.server` is pretty simplistic and doesn't handle things like hot-reloading well. It would be nice if Python, or at least Sphinx, came with something that would do this better (I could have sworn I remembered Sphinx coming with a live server, but I can't find documentation for that now, so maybe I'm confused with something else).